# Multiview applications in android

Tags: android, view

I want to develop a multi-window application. For example, the first screen (view) - login, the second view - GPS map etc.
What tool is best to use for this application? Is it right to use ViewFlipper? (android 2.2 or 2.3, not 4+).
Thanks.

Comment: You can use tab or fragment in android.There are lot's of tutorial on google.

Comment: You can use ViewFlipper, ViewPager, ViewSwitcher, TabActivity, Fragments, multiple Activities - all depends on your specific requirements and preferences.  Start by reading documentation and tutorials - it'll help.

Comment: ViewPager/Fragments are not supported in Android 2.2/2.3. ViewSwitcher may content 2 views, no more. Activities may be destroyed